# Apache server stops

Tags: apache, ssh, cpanel

i dont know why; but my apache server is crashing about every hour since this morning .. to overcome the problem, i'm just restarting the apache via `service restart httpd` command on ssh.

there is no program using ram. when i write TOP comment on ssh, it says 220mb of 8gb ram is free. but niether mysql nor httpd or php etc is using any ram or cpu.

```
8gb total ram - 7939112 used - 225136 free

top usage:

mysql = 0.7% cpu, 9.3% mem

php   = 0.7% cpu, 0.1% mem

httpd = 0.7% cpu, 0 mem
```

my system details: centos, cpanel, apache

what should i do? i also dont get any error email from cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to task manager to see which of the ones you have listed is taking the most memory.   Also if you are using owncloud this is the biggest hoger of memory.  Now if it is apache is you need to determine if it is one of the services you have running that is rendering most of the memory.  But if it is not of the services and it is apache then you might have try reninstalling apache again.  But before you uninstall apache disable mysql or any server type like mysql to see if that could be the issue, if so then there is service running hard that needs to be deleted or checked because is talking to something.  Check your task manager and see what is taking the most memory and start from there.

Comment: task manager on apache server? where is it? i just know TOP comment on ssh like this. and also, i can not delete apache or mysql etc.. there are running web sites on server.

Comment: What I meant was to right click on the bottom of your task bar or ctrl+alt+del and click on your task manager to check what is hogging memory the most from your computer.  Now if you have multiple sites running and is meant for people to go in and out of your sites then it could be that your sites are getting hit hard...  If not please explain a little more in order to decipher the issue or problem.

Comment: as i write on my question, i use CENTOS opertion system on my server. and there is jump/increasing on hits.

Comment: If you are getting a more than normal hits on the server then you might need to either upgrade some of the hardware like memory or get not server and dived the load like a load balancer or move it off sight.  Another question if you have centos on a VM, you should be able to set it max memory use to 4gigs.  If not then you need to do one of the above.  If there is more let me and also rate me.